# react-admin: <Show> component elements not rendering when wrapped inside divs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, jsx, react-admin

I'm currently working on an admin portal using react-admin, and I've been able to seamlessly style it using MaterialUI, specifically its [makeStyles](https://github.com/health-espresso/project-zeus/pull/5) hook. The way I've done it is I'd import my makeStyles file that looks similar to this:

```
export const detailsView = makeStyles({
  detail: {
    width: "100%",
    "& div": {
      display: "Block",
      visibility: "Visible",
    }
  }
export default detailsView
```

into my main component, that would hold, for example, a List component like this:

```
export const ExampleList = (props) => {
  const classes = importedStyles();
  return (
    <>
      <h2 className={classes.tableTitle}>Example Header</h2>
      <List {...props} className={classNames(classes.table)}>
        <Datagrid rowClick="edit">
          <ReferenceField source="id" reference="users" label="Name">
            <FunctionField
              label="Name"
              render={(record) => `${record.first_name} ${record.last_name}`}
            />
          </ReferenceField>
          <TextField source="title"/>
          <DateField source="date" />
        </Datagrid>
      </List>
    </>
  );
};

export default ExampleList;
```

If I had to wrap my own `div` that would also hold a section of a `TextField`, everything still works according to plan. However, this is only the case with the `List`, `Edit`, `Filter`, and `Create`, **however**, I'm unable to properly style the `Show` component.

Prior to adding any styles or wrapping some fields up in a `div`, this is how it would look like: [image] Notice how the name shows up just fine.

However, when I wrap the `Person Details` header with the rendered name, as seen below:

```
 <div className={detailClasses.detailSection}>
          <h3 className={ detailClasses.detailSectionTitle}>Person Details</h3>
          <ReferenceField
            source="id"
            reference="users"
            label="Name"
            className={detailClasses.detailSectionInfo}
          >
            <FunctionField
              render={(record) => `${record.first_name} ${record.last_name}`}
            />
          </ReferenceField>
        </div>
```

then the information that I want rendered (in this case, the person's name), then it completely stops rendering and doesn't show up on the page. [image]

This hasn't happened with any other react-admin component that I mentioned somewhere above.
I was wondering why this is the case, and why it is only happening with the `Show` component.

Thanks in advance!